# Why can't write certificate.crt with acme?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, acme

```
root@vultr:~# systemctl  status  nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-07-28 02:16:44 UTC; 23min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
 Main PID: 12999 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1148)
   Memory: 8.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─12999 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─13000 nginx: worker process

Jul 28 02:16:44 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jul 28 02:16:44 vultr.guest systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Jul 28 02:16:44 vultr.guest systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

The nginx is in good status.
I want to create and write certificate.crt with acme:

```
sudo su -l -s /bin/bash acme
curl  https://get.acme.sh | sh
export CF_Key="xxxx"
export CF_Email="yyyy@yahoo.com"
```

`CF_Key` is my global api key in cloudflare,`CF_Email` is the register email to login  cloudflare.

```
acme@vultr:~$ acme.sh --issue --dns dns_cf -d  domain.com --debug 2
```

The output content is so long that i can't post here,so i upload into the termbin.com ,we share the link below:

```
https://termbin.com/taxl
```

Please open the webpage,you can get the whole output info,and check which result in error,there are two main issues:
1.My nginx server is in good status,acme.sh can't detect it.
2.How can set the config file?

```
[Wed Jul 28 03:04:38 UTC 2021] config file is empty, can not read CA_EAB_KEY_ID
[Wed Jul 28 03:04:38 UTC 2021] config file is empty, can not read CA_EAB_HMAC_KEY
[Wed Jul 28 03:04:38 UTC 2021] config file is empty, can not read CA_EMAIL
```

To write key into specified directory:

```
acme.sh --install-cert -d domain.com     
        --key-file /usr/local/etc/certfiles/private.key     
        --fullchain-file /usr/local/etc/certfiles/certificate.crt
```

It encounter problem:

```
[Tue Jul 27 01:12:15 UTC 2021] Installing key to:/usr/local/etc/certfiles/private.key
cat: /home/acme/.acme.sh/domain.com/domain.com.key: No such file or directory
```

To check files in `/usr/local/etc/certfiles/`

```
ls  /usr/local/etc/certfiles/
private.key
```

No `certificate.crt`  in  `/usr/local/etc/certfiles/`.
How to fix then?

Comment: How did you install acme?

Comment: curl  https://get.acme.sh | sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From acme.sh v3.0.0, acme.sh is using Zerossl as default ca, you must
> register the account first(one-time) before you can issue new certs.

[Here](https://zerossl.com/letsencrypt-alternative/) is how ZeroSSL compares with LetsEncrypt.

#### With ZeroSSL as CA

You must register at ZeroSSL before issuing a certificate. To register run the below command (assuming yyyy@yahoo.com is email with which you want to register)

```
acme.sh --register-account -m yyyy@yahoo.com
```

Now you can issue a new certificate (assuming you have set `CF_Key` & `CF_Email` or `CF_Token` & `CF_Account_ID`)

```
acme.sh --issue --dns dns_cf -d  domain.com
```

#### Without ZeroSSL as CA

If you don't want to use ZeroSSL and say want to use LetsEncrypt instead, then you can provide the server option to issue a certificate

```
 acme.sh --issue --dns dns_cf -d  domain.com --server letsencrypt
```

[Here](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/Server) are more options for the CA server.